# Is this statement true? Simplified sum of matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra

Is this true? If so, how does it work?

$$
\sum_1^n (AS^Ts_i)(s_i^TSA^T) = (AS^TS)(S^TSA^T)
$$

Here, $s_i$ are the columns of $S$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed true. We have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n (AS^Ts_i)(s_i^TSA^T) = AS^T\left(\sum_{i=1}^n s_is_i^T \right)SA^T = AS^T(SS^T)SA^T.
$$
One way to see that $SS^T = \sum_{i=1}^n s_is_i^T$ is to use [block matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_multiplication) to expand
$$
SS^T = \pmatrix{s_1 & \cdots & s_n} \pmatrix{s_1^T\\ \vdots \\ s_n^T}.
$$

Comment: I'm more concerned about the factoring, is this correct for a two columns S? $(AS^Ts_1)(s_1^TSA^T) + (AS^Ts_2)(s_2^TSA^T) = $ $AS^T(s_1 s_1^T SA^T + s_2s_2^TSA^T) = $ $AS^T(s_1s_1^T + s_2s_2^T)SA^T$?

Comment: @Frank Yes, that's right